# How do I handle/Implement System.Web.Editor.ComponentLocator in VS2015, v14

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, vsix, visual-studio-lightbulbs

I"m not too familiar with Visual Studio Extention development, and the documentation on ***migrating an existing vs extension*** to vs2015 seems fairly non-existent, or just [unhelpful to underline type usages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512930.aspx).

Never-the-less, I've cloned **Mads Kristensen's** ***JSON intellisense*** git project so that I can modify it to support VS2015.

---

I'm having an issue with a class method reference in the latest (version 14)`Microsoft.Web.Editor.dll` assembly. `Microsoft.Web.Editor.ComponentLocatorWithOrdering<T>.ImportMany()`. It seems to have been removed from the assembly, and I am unable to determine what the proper approach/implementation is in the latest assembly.

```
  ...
    private readonly ItemHandlerRegistry<IJSONSmartTagProvider> _smartTagProviders;

    private void RegisterSmartTagProviders()
    {
        // using Microsoft.Web.Editor;
        IEnumerable<Lazy<IJSONSmartTagProvider>> providers = ComponentLocatorWithOrdering<IJSONSmartTagProvider>.ImportMany();

        foreach (Lazy<IJSONSmartTagProvider> provider in providers)
        {
            _smartTagProviders.RegisterHandler(provider.Value.ItemType, provider.Value);
        }
    }
  ...
```

The best reference I have for the v12 assembly, type, and method is from [whatdll.com](http://whatdll.com/type/ManyImporter.html). It doesn't describe it; Nor does it provide any material in regards to it in the context of migration (which is ultimately what I'm posting this question for).

#### Additional considers

The `IJSONSmartTagProvder` type is a custom type that seems to encapsulate  `SmartTag`, which is depreciated (or deprecated).. The newer (recommended) type is `SuggestedAction` (which seems to be an interface to a concept/compontent referred to as **Lightbulb**), but even if I were to convert the code/custom types to utilize the newer type, I wouldn't necessarily know how to utilize it in the latest `Microsoft.Web.Editor` assembly in a similiar manner to how Mads is using his types in the above snippet. (also, the only implementing class I've seen of `ISuggestedAction` is in [Rosyln](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures/Implementation/Suggestions/SuggestedAction.cs,4)).

Comment: hmm.. can someone wtih 1500 rep add `lightbulb` as a tag to this question..

Comment: Check how https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/blob/master/EditorExtensions/CSS/SmartTags/CssSmartTagger.cs#L86 works

Comment: actually.. from the Roslyn source reference I posted in the question above, I see  `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Tagging` reference as being similar to what Mad's `JSONSmartTagger` class (which is the class this method is part of) is doing...

Comment: thanks @SLaks, I'll look into it..

Comment: Also, the better way to do this is to MEF-`[Import]` the `IEnumerable<Lazy<IJSONSmartTagProvider>>` from a MEF-exported class.